# Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate from my login screen to the home screen using a pressable button. However, the code that I now have gives the following error: *Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?*. The error is aimed on row 8 (const navigation = useNavigation();).
**LoginButton.js:**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, Pressable, Button } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import styles from "./styles";
import HomeScreen from "../../screens/Home";

const LoginButton = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttontext}>Login</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoginButton;
```

The LoginButton is inserted as a component in the LoginItem inside the last <View. **LoginItem.js:**

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";
import LoginButton from "../LoginButton";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const LoginItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.logincontainer}>
      {/* Background image of the login screen */}
      <Image
        source={require("../../../assets/images/blue-sky-start-screen.jpg")}
        style={styles.loginbackground}
        blurRadius={4}
      ></Image>
      {/* Title of the login screen */}
      <View style={styles.titlecontainer}>
        <Text style={styles.companytitle}>BestelSnel</Text>
      </View>
      {/* Login button */}
      <View style={styles.loginbutton}>
        <LoginButton></LoginButton>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoginItem;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`useNavigation` only works if your component is inside of a `NavigationContainer` and a `Navigator` like mentioned on the getting-started-page:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

`HomeScreen` would be your `LoginItem`

Comment: Thank you Christian your answer helped me. For others that are still stuck: I used the structure above in my App.js and assigned both <Stack.Screen name="LoginItem" component={LoginItem}/> and <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />. It makes  much more sense now.

Comment: @JeffreyChong would you mind marking the answer as correct?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I got this error because autocomplete added the wrong import statement.

`import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";`

but the one I needed is:

`import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";`

Hope this helps anybody to save some minutes.

Comment: After a lot of navigation mock and research finally this solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, and the accepted answer did not work for me.

What I did get working on was importing the component I wanted to go to and using that in the `navigate()` call. Generally, this probably means just removing the quotes so your param to that function is a Component and not a String.

Given the code from the question, the code would be:

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate(Home)}
```

Very similar to the original, just minus the quotes, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing the params correctly also, but params had a react component in it. That's why it was giving this error.

// product should not have a react component
props.navigation.navigate(ROUTE_TEST, {product});

Answer (score 0):

This error came up also, when I assigned the useNavigation hook in a file with no Class or Functional components that can be rendered. such as the App.js file that only contained the Navigation and Stack components